# IntelliJ IDEA error 1172 with Flex project

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea, apache-flex, compiler-errors

I switched to IntelliJ IDEA for my Flex projects.

I just try to import a project in a new IntelliJ project, set up this project with the source (I can go to all my classes if I click on an occurence of the imports so the links are OK right ?), but when I try to build, I have the 1172 error with some simple classes : "Error:(19, 0) [TestProject]: Error code: 1172: Definition fr.romarin.utils:TimeUtils could not be found."

The same class imported and used in a new fresh project with the same setup is OK.

```
private function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
        TimeUtils.formatLessThanTen(1); // works
    }
```

So what is the problem ?

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after 2 days stucked, I finally fix my problem.

I don't know why but contrary to Flash Builder and FDT to load the locales like in [the Adobe doc](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-localization-pt2.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader), IntelliJ doesn't like theses commands and has his own found in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyciNPirDSE).

After these changes, everything is OK and I could finally compile my project.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I found the problem but not how to fix it yet :

It comes from my commands arguments to compile locales files :

```
-locale en_US fr_FR
-source-path ./src/locale/{locale}
-allow-source-path-overlap=true
```

As soon as I add these commands, I have got the 1172 and 1120 with some classes.

However, these commands work in Flash Builder or FDT.

So what's wrong ?

Thx.